# Multidimensional array by user input

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I'm suppose to read in a user-made matrix and print it out using a 2d array, but its not working. It goes into an infinite loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int numrow, input = 0;
    while(cin)
    {
        cout << "Enter Row: " << endl;
        cin >> input;
        numrow++;
    }
    int b[numrow][numrow];
    for (int i = 0; i < numrow; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < numrow; j++)
        {
            input >> b[i][j];
            cout << b[i][j];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "not working"

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: You did not initialize `int numrow`... Also I wonder how this compiles ? `int b[numrow][numrow];` is not const. The compiler will not accept this. Either use `new` to allocate the memory, or even better: [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while(cin){` is the problem, you don't have any `break`s in your while loop. 
You could replace it with an `if` statement. Also remember to initialize your variables before you use them: `int numrow = 0, input = 0;`

```
b[i][j] = input; // you probably meant to do this
```